# Responsive Tabs jQuery

Tags: jquery, joomla, tabs, conflict

I am trying to integrate [Responsive Tabs jQuery](http://www.petelove.com/2013/01/17/responsive-tabs-jquery-script/) developed by Pete Love with Joomla 3. after success installed, I got problem about this. The problem is jquery conflict with another application as usual. I suspect this code as root caused :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'></script>
```

Why that is as my suspect, becuase when i tried to rename this url name, the conflict was solve. Beside that, I also tried to add this syntax `jQuery.noConflict();`  to prevent a conflict, but the result was same. Below is the jquery code :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo JURI::base();;?>modules/mod_tabresponsive/js/responsiveTabs.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        RESPONSIVEUI.responsiveTabs();
    })
    </script>`
```

Maybe, anyone know about this problem and help to find the solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: since joomla 3.0 already has jQuery, why are you including it again?

Comment: My J!3.0 site has jQuery 1.7.1 running in noConflict mode. Use $jq, not $. You may need to search/replace your plugin file.

Comment: `;;` << I would have thought you would be getting an error from this. But more towards the point, @Marko is correct. jQuery was included in Joomla 3.0 as it uses Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); ?>
```

To call the jQuery framework in Joomla 3. This will also call no conflict by default!

Also remove the one of the two semi-colon's in you JURI::base() command

Comment: Thanks all for your advise, so you mean we just replace this code : `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'></script>` with `<?php JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); ?>`. Is it enough ?

Comment: Yup :) but it will be called in non-conflict so remember to reassign the $ variable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your idea, now the problem has been solved.
Yes, your answer is correct. 
I used `<?php JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); ?>` to replace `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js` and I change the whole `$` with `jQuery`. Now it works properly.

Thank you very much :-)